# Vertical alignment when using { or math symbols

Tags: vertical-alignment

How can I adjust the vertical alignment in the following table for the cell which have for example the value `\{0.91,0.15\}`:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{c C{2cm} C{2cm} C{2cm} C{2cm}}
\toprule[1.5pt]
\multirow{2}{*}{days} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Time in \{Min,Sec\}} \\ \cmidrule[1.5pt](){2-5}
      & D         & M     & A    & N     \\ \hline
6                         & \{5,15\}     &         &         &         \\ \hline
6                         &      \{0.91,0.15\}       &         &         &         \\ \hline
6                         &     \{99,0.5\}      &         &    \{77,22\}       &         \\ \hline
6                         &             &         &    \{0.31,0.15\}     &         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2):

The spacing issue seems to apply to just about all the rows in the table, so I would suggest you set `\arraystretch` to say `1.2` to widen the spacing between rows.  You can do this via

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
```

Putting this command inside the `table` environment will make it local to that environment.

Had this been a one off, then you could have inserted a rule of zero width and appropriate height and depth to force the lines apart by writing the entry as

```
\vrule width 0pt height 12pt depth 5pt \{0.91,0.15\}
```

for example.

Here is the `\arraystretch` version:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\begin{table}[h]\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{c C{2cm} C{2cm} C{2cm} C{2cm}}
\toprule[1.5pt]
\multirow{2}{*}{days} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Time in \{Min,Sec\}} \\ \cmidrule[1.5pt](){2-5}
      & D         & M     & A    & N     \\ \hline
6                         & \{5,15\}     &         &         &         \\ \hline
6                         &      \{0.91,0.15\}       &         &         &         \\ \hline
6                         &     \{99,0.5\}      &         &    \{77,22\}       &         \\ \hline
6                         &             &         &    \{0.31,0.15\}     &         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `booktabs` rules, not `\hline`; however, avoiding too many rules is better; I'll present two realizations of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


\begin{table}[htp]

\begin{tabular}{c C{2cm} C{2cm} C{2cm} C{2cm}}
\toprule
days & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Time in \{Min,\,Sec\}} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
   & D               & M       & A               & N  \\
\midrule
6  & \{5,\,15\}      &         &                 &    \\
6  & \{0.91,\,0.15\} &         &                 &    \\
6  & \{99,\,0.5\}    &         & \{77,\,22\}     &    \\
6  &                 &         & \{0.31,\,0.15\} &    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{c C{2cm} C{2cm} C{2cm} C{2cm}}
\toprule
days & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Time in \{Min,\,Sec\}} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
   & D               & M       & A               & N  \\
\midrule
6  & \{5,\,15\}      &         &                 &    \\
\midrule
6  & \{0.91,\,0.15\} &         &                 &    \\
\midrule
6  & \{99,\,0.5\}    &         & \{77,\,22\}     &    \\
\midrule
6  &                 &         & \{0.31,\,0.15\} &    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]